# Avoid Cache misses in Java

Tags: java, caching, garbage-collection

Currently im switching my state of mind to develop applications more cache friendly.
In C++ im using stack allocation where i can,also i'm holding data with this same purpose in one array(Data Driven Programming) etc...
But im also Java developer and there comes a question:
I heard that Java is "cache miss generator".
Everything there is in heap,and is scattered in whole RAM after allocation or garbage collector work.I think the same problem is with C#.
Will it have sense to write Java in Data Driven way?
Is there any way to optimize Java code,or we are stuck with Java automatic optimization and cache misses?

Comment: This is not about C++, so I recommend you remove the C++ tag.

Comment: Your question is unclear - do you wish to develop cache mechanism in Java?  there are several good 3rd party libraries that do that.  If you wish to optimize the JVM garbage collector, you can rest assured that it is far superior in perforamnce and efficiency to any thing you will attempt to develop yourself.

Comment: @sharonbn unclear to you, pretty clear to me; OP wants to avoid "cache killer" data layouts, which is nontrivial in Java because there are no value types.

Comment: How much do you care about performance? And if it is enough, could it make sense to choose the tool based on the problem at hand? If cache misses are your problem it might be much better to use C, C++ or C# rather than Java...

Comment: @sharonbn I dont want modify garbage collector.But i know it copies everything around so it messes a bit structure.I want avoid this as much as i can.

Comment: why do you care so much about how the garbage collector manages memory allocation? the fact that memory is not contiguous does not testify about anything. how do you know there is ANY performance degradation at all? maybe it is doing so to gain better performance?

Comment: @sharonbn I suggest you go read up about spatial and temporal locality. On modern hardware, a program can spend most of its time waiting for L2/L3 cache fetches instead of doing computations. Of course, that's not really an issue for a lot of programs and for most of the code in those programs.

Comment: in this case, I believe @David Rodriguez was right.  Trying to manage physical memory with Java is like trying to develop front end with C.  Java is not designed for this kind of considerations, in fact, it is intentionally designed to obscure them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> In C++ im using stack allocation where i can,also i'm holding data with this same purpose in one array(Data Driven Programming) etc...

In Java it will automatically place short live obejcts on the stack using Escape Analysis.  I wouldn't worry about this unless you see in a profiler that this is an issue.  Even then it could be that the profiler is preventing the escape analysis from working and it is not a problem in a real program.

> I heard that Java is "cache miss generator".

Java had far more referencing than C++ or C# code which has been written to use structs or objects which are embedded inside objects.  How much difference this makes depends on how sensitive your application is to micro-tuning.

> Everything there is in heap,and is scattered in whole RAM after allocation or garbage collector work.I think the same problem is with C#.

Java (and C#) is not a random memory arranger either.  In theory the objects could be anywhere, but in practice they are not usually.  Consider if you have;

```
class A { }

class B {
    A a = new A();
}
```

If you create a `B`, the `A` could be anywhere, but generally it is not.  When Java allocates memory in the Eden space it is usually continuous in memory.  This is the simplest and most efficient way to allocate memory.  This means that 99.9% of the time, `A` will be immediately after `B`, possibly on the same cache line.  In fact "false sharing" is a real problem in Java for some use cases. i.e. when you would like to two objects which are not on the same cache line.

What happens on a GC?

In the OpenJDK/Oracle JVM, objects are copied in reverse order of discovery. i.e. `A` would appear immediately before `B` in most cases.

> Will it have sense to write Java in Data Driven way?

This case be the case, and in < 1% of cases this can make a big difference.  However, for most of your code, if not most of your applications, you will have much, much bigger problems to worry about.

> Is there any way to optimize Java code,or we are stuck with Java automatic optimization and cache misses?

You can use `Unsafe` to control memory structures of your choice.  We (Chronicle Software) have libraries which allow you do just that, but even though we would love you to use our services, in 99% cases, there is no good reason to worry about this sort of micro-tuning.  Only in extreme cases would it make any real difference.

> I dont want modify garbage collector.But i know it copies everything around so it messes a bit structure.I want avoid this as much as i can.

This is what the GC does. It packs together related objects, not just for efficiency but because copying objects in the manner they are found is the simplest implementation.  Arranging data randomly is something you would have to do deliberately if you wanted that and it would be more work. e.g. if you want to avoid "false sharing" it is non-trivial.

Comment: Lets assume im writing again game using JMonkey. The standard way it works is something like rootNode and in rootNode are spatials that updates modifiers and this modifiers updates this spatial,everything ordered by position in modifiers list(classical),so it looks like.move-think-updatePositioninPhysicWorld... and next object again similar pattern but can be even other sequence cuz of delete/adding new modifiers.So when i organize it in data driven pattern move-move-move think-think-think will it impact performance in Java or its completly useless?

Comment: @pszczelaszkov it might but it probably won't. If it does it could cost you 10 - 30 ns say 1 - 10% of the time. e.g. if you end up hitting L3 instead of L1.  How important is that to you?  If its important, denormalise your data structure to make it more memory efficient.

Comment: I'm no longer familiar with Java, but a few question arise, first on *Escape analysis*: If the body does: `A a = new A(); object.function(a);` can the compiler figure out whether `object` may be storing a reference to `a`? The naïve answer is that it is not obvious, I could see escape analysis failing for any case where a function is called passing the object.

Comment: On locality: In the case of `class B { A a = new A(); }`, Yes, the `a` object will be laid out right after the `B` containing object, but each object has an overhead (which I believe is 8 bytes for 32bits, 16bytes for 64bits), that means that the actual contents of `a` are 8/16 bytes out from the `B` object. Have a couple of members and the spread might be enough that it affects computations (consider `ArrayList<Integer>`, initialized in a single shot, yes all `Integer` objects will be together, but all underlying `int` are separated by 8/16 bytes.

Comment: ... furthermore, in C or C++ you can tweak the members in an object to place the *hot* data towards the beginning of the cache-line, slightly more efficient specially for large objects where later cache lines may not be needed, the fact that the GC may reorder the members in memory, making all this reasoning useless. **Disclaimer**: My first guess is that all of this is really not the right place to spend time optimizing, specially before previous *profiling*, It's been a few years since I've been in a situation where I cared about cache efficiency

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas this is true however the rate cpus can load caches is pretty fast and you find that int [] vs ArrayList<Integer> shows surprisingly little difference for sequential access. For random access, it still matters which is why you might use arrays or off heap memory instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can improve cache performance in Java too, but it is involved. Arrays of primitive types are contiguous blocks of memory, so as long as you can rewrite your code in terms of those you are golden.  As Stepanov said, you can write FORTRAN in any language. I have seen this actually being done in the past, but it is not *nice*...

C# on the other hand is a friendlier language to this respect. `struct` types have contiguous members, so you can build higher level cache friendly abstractions in C#, additionally `List<T>` for a *value-type* `T` is allocated in a single contiguous block of memory.

Answer (score 3):

My first advice would be not to spend a lot of time worrying about it unless you have specific performance targets you are not meeting. Furthermore, there are a lot of other avenues to explore in writing efficient Java code.

... but, if you really want to do down this path you could consider the "lightweight object" pattern (or flyweight): [Wikipedia flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).

Arrays and classes of primitives are probably going to occupy consecutive storage, so you could use these objects for underlying storage and use adapter classes sitting on top to return an OO representation of the data.

You would have to be careful not to allocate to many of the adapters. Perhaps a cursor type pattern might be useful with one adapter object passed a reference into the underlying data array.

Answer (score 2):

You can optimize for cache misses, but it involves dealing with artificially convoluted class hierarchies, lots of arrays or go the `sun.misc.Unsafe` road which adds its own overhead.

Java provides very few guarantees about memory layout. You have two strong guarantees:

- Fields of a superclass are kept together in memory (can be useful to avoid false sharing without resorting to `sun.misc.Contended`)
- Arrays are contiguous in memory

It's hard to give general advice other than "don't worry too much about it", but in general simple strategies work best.

Use `ArrayList` instead of `LinkedList`, `HashMap` instead of `TreeMap` when possible.

If you need more control, go for open addressing maps, specifically if you're dealing with primitive types (there are a few decent libraries out there).

Be mindful of what other threads are doing to your cache and how big your working set size is. Sometimes it pays off to pause parallel threads doing related work to ensure they don't drift off too much apart in memory and thrash your cache.

As with all optimization problems, benchmark often (learn to use JMH) and use data to drive your optimization efforts.